# JavaScript getElementById get to the second DIV

Tags: javascript, maps

why can't I display Google map the the second DIV ID?
I tried to change my Map_canvas to Class same results
I want to display Google map in he second DIv map_canvas
the Map runs on my jQueryMobile so I need to get to the second Div in the display page

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
            } else {
                error('Geo Location is not supported');
            }
        });

        function success(position) {
            debugger;
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            var options = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_maps").children[0], options);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                title: "You are here!"
            });
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my_maps">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just say document.getElementById("map_canvas")

Comment: The first child of the `<div>` may be a (blank) text node.

Comment: @Pointy Text nodes are not included in the `.children[]` array.

Comment: If you are including the library jquery, why not using that instead of getelementbyid ?

Comment: Exactly. Use $("#map_canvas")

Comment: @Kolink ah sorry; I was thinking of `childNodes` (I don't do enough direct DOM manipulation lately :-)  (However *I think* old versions of IE would include comment nodes, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: I used direct document.getElementById("map_canvas") but when adding the first DIV it stoped working

Comment: how should I write with jQuery element

Comment: @user1377921 mplungjan just showed how: $("#map_canvas"), but I don't think there is anything wrong with your DOM selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not how you select the DOM element.
Try specifying `width` and `height` for your wrapping div (and the map-div should fit it).

```
<div id="my_maps" style="width:100%; height:500px;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

And, although there is no problem using `.children[]` with the parent node; this should be faster:

```
document.getElementById('map_canvas');
```